# Qt QNetworkAccessManager with SSL

Tags: qt, ssl, connection

i'm completely new to SSL (and newbee to Qt, too). I want to create a SSL encrypted connection and haven't found any good examples concerning the general structure.

```
QNetworkAccessManager qnam;
QSslConfiguration sslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
SslConfiguration.setProtocol(QSsl::SslV3);
QNetworkRequest req;
req.setSslConfiguration(sslConfiguration);
req.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.address.tld/"));

QNetworkReply *rep = qnam->get(req);
```

is this how it works or do i have to do anything further?

greetings

Comment: Usually you don't even have to set a configuration on the request, as it's going to use the default one (and *that* is the one that should be properly set up). Apart from that, yes, that's the structure. SSL is almost transparent, apart from error handling.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you asked this question at a time when there were no examples that you could follow. At the moment there are several examples. Go to the Welcome page in QT Creator and select Examples (under the Projects button in the left pane.) Then type "ssl" into the search box. On my system I see three examples. HTH.